# Mouse button problems: hardware or software?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, mouse, touchpad, right-click

I have been having a problem that seems to defy my usual notion that a computer problem must be either a hardware problem or a software problem. Specifically, when graphical demands on my computer are high, as measured by number of tabs and windows open, my mouse buttons begin to respond strangely (actually, built-in touchpad buttons on a Dell Inspiron). The left mouse button loses its ability to grab and move or grab and resize windows, even though the pointer changes to the usual grab handle tip when positioned correctly. Likewise, the left mouse button loses its ability to start and end text selection with a drag. The right-hand mouse button stops producing context menus and either does nothing or acts acts like a left-click. These problems all go away if I close enough windows.

I'd also note that if I do any of the things listed above a large number of times, like 20 to 40, it will often eventually do what it is supposed to do.  This is what initially made me think this was a hardware problem with the touchpad buttons. But I don't see how this is consistant with the problem only occuring under high demand.

Has anyone ever encountered a similar problem? Ny idea what causes it or how I might make it go away?

I am working in a Windows 10 environment with three monitors of different sizes, coordinated with DisplayFusion Pro.

Comment: What I suggest you do first is try an external mouse.  If that works, try updating the Dell drivers for the touchpad.

Comment: This is clearly a software issue.